What insulation is this

What kind of insulation is this? Could it contain asbestos?

You need to have it tested to know.  Picture will not tell.  The two 2x4s might be a more important question depending on the use.  The wires shown look like low voltage, but if house voltage wires are like that, that is important also(not good).

This is an attic. What do you mean about the 2x4s?

They seem quite short at the joint, but I do not know what they are.

@Chris Could it contain asbestos? ... what leads you to believe that the answer could ever be a no?

Could it be rock wool? It looks similar.

Yes it could, especially if the house was built before 1978. Asbestos in my opinion, back in the day was a "miracle" mineral. It was used in siding, flooring and insulation. That don't mean it is in that insulation you have there. I was an insulator for a while, and it looks like cellulose, ground up paper, but that still doesn't mean it will be asbestos free. That is where testing comes in as crip659 recommended.
There are test kits online available for around $35.
